# Swift: addTarget only works for the first element of an array

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, custom-controls

I have a problem with the [sixth chapter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH19-SW1) of the basic Swift tutorial from Apple.

The problem is that only the first star (UIButton) is working. I created all the stars in a for loop and call for every UIButton the addTarget method once. So basically the code is the same for every button. And now a very strange behavior is coming up, on the iPad simulators everything is working fine in differnce to this on all iPhones Simulators < iPhone 6 no star works and on all other iPhones only the first star is working, same on my real iPhone 6.

init method with for loop:

```
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    let filledStarImage = UIImage(named: "filledStar")
    let emptyStarImage = UIImage(named: "emptyStar")

    for _ in 0..<starCount {
        let button = UIButton()

        button.setImage(emptyStarImage, forState: .Normal)
        button.setImage(filledStarImage, forState: .Selected)
        button.setImage(filledStarImage, forState: [.Highlighted, .Selected])

        button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
        ratingButtons += [button]
        ratingButtons.last!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
        self.addSubview(button)
    }

}
```

action method:

```
func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton){
    rating = ratingButtons.indexOf(button)! + 1
    updateButtonSelectionState()
}

func updateButtonSelectionState() {
    for (index, button) in ratingButtons.enumerate(){
        button.selected = index < rating
    }
}
```

layout subviews method:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    let buttonSize = Int(frame.size.height)
    var buttonFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonSize , height: buttonSize)
    for (index, button) in ratingButtons.enumerate() {
        buttonFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(index * (buttonSize + spacing))
        button.frame = buttonFrame
    }
    updateButtonSelectionState()
}
override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
    let buttonSize = Int(frame.size.height)
    let width = buttonSize * starCount + spacing * (starCount - 1)
    return CGSize(width: width, height: buttonSize)
}
```

Do you have any suggestions how to make the buttons working on every device?

Comment: Don't you set the `frame`s of the buttons anywhere?

Comment: ohh yes I forgot to provide the layoutSubviews() method for you - question edited

Comment: ok problem disappears all buttons are working fine right now